# Automation Testing using protractor,typepscript and jasmine

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

Recently I got placed in new company, they are using automation testing using protractor,jasmine and Type script. Actually I have a experience in selenium with java  but I don't know the protractor. Please tell me how  can I start protractor testing? Is there any relation between protractor,jasmine and type script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **PROTRACTOR:** In general,you can say that  protractor is outer new layer of selenium to support some additional locators of angular js like ng-model,ng-binding,ng-repeater etc. Rest functionality of protractor is almost same as selenium.
>
> **JASMINE:** Whereas Jasmine is a framework by using that ,we will write our test-cases.
>   Some of the keywords to write test-case using Jasmine are Describe(){it()} etc.
>
> **TYPESCRIPT:** Type-Script is the super-set of java-script. .Now its our choice to write our test-cases in java-script or type script.

So by concluding the whole story,I can say that 
when we have a scenario to test angular applications, we will then use protractor.js to automate angular applications by using jasmine framework written in JavaScript/typescript.

Comment: Thank you all,now i got some idea about protractor,typescript and jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

1) Learn Typescript : Its more looks Java 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html

2) async and await (Protrctor will drop selenium control flow)
https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.4.0/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait

```
// LoginPageTest.ts
describe('Protractor Typescript TestCase Demo', function() {
it('Test case Name',async function (){
    let loginpage:LoginPage = new LoginPage(browser);
    await loginpage.EnterUserName(XL);
    await loginpage.IsTextPresentInUserName(XL); 
});
});

export class LoginPage extends Pagebase
constructor(common){ this.driv=common; }
Username            = element(  by.id('userName'));

public async EnterUserName(XL:Map<string,string>) {
await this.clickClearType( this.driv,   this.UserName,  await AXL.get("userName")); 
}

//Pagebase.ts
constructor(common){ this.driv=common;}
public async clickClearType(elementn,textvalue){
    try { 
        await this.driv.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions
            .elementToBeClickable(elementn), 15000, 
            'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
        // Click
        await elementn.click();
        // clear 
        await elementn.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'a'));
        await elementn.sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE);
        // Type
        await elementn.sendKeys(textvalue);();

        console.log("Element Clicked Success" );
    } 
    catch (error) {
        // Handle errors here
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i will refer the links what you mentioned in above.

Answer (score -1):

To learn protractor, read [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/). this site has enough examples with api references.
After you get strong with concepts of protractor and async nature, try changes with typescript.. this would help.